# Load balancing efficiency terminology

Tags: parallel-processing, computer-science, terminology

Suppose I run some software on a parallel computer and that, during the execution, an average of X % of the processors are active. What is the correct compsci term for X? Would 'load' be correct?

Comment: I'd suggest reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Although related to computer science, I'm inclined towards saying that your question might be slightly off the usual topic in SO.

Comment: @SamiLaine There is a *terminology* tag so this type of question seems acceptable to me...

Comment: True, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe **utilization** is a better term than 'load', at least it is widely used, see for example the paper below:

> Aida, Kento and Kasahara, Hironori and Narita, Seinosuke: Job scheduling scheme for pure space sharing among rigid jobs, Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol. 1459, pp. 98–121, 1998.